# Storage not returning string ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've implemented [Storage for Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) (don't know if it's something new to store values).

I've created a service that stores an `object` (it works, because I've console.logged() it), but when I want to `get()` it's returning me `undefined` when I use the same key, even when the `console.log()` from the `get()` method prints what I want...

```
getInfo(keystorage): string {
    var val = null;  
        this.storage.get(keystorage).then((profile) => {
            val = JSON.parse(profile);
            console.log(val["info"]); //returning what I want
            return val["info"];
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
            return 'catchhhh';
        });
        return val;
    }
```

It's returning `null` now because I've added  `var vall = null` and looks like it doesn't change anything...

I store it like this:

```
saveInfo(usr){
    if(usr==null) return;
    var usertostore = {"id": currentUser["id"], "info":currentUser["info"]};
    this.storage.set("userLoged",JSON.stringify(usertostore ))
  }
```

I'm trying to get the info like this:

```
var userInfo = this.storageService.getInfo('myKey');
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because the storage method is asynchronous and the value is null when it is returned.

Can you try this way?

```
getInfo(keystorage) {
    return this.storage.get(keystorage);
}

saveInfo(usr){
    if(usr==null) return;
    var usertostore = {"id": 1234, "info":"fdsgf"};
    this.storage.set("userLoged",JSON.stringify(usertostore ))
}
```

and get the info:

```
getInfo('userLoged').then((res) => {
  var userInfo = res;
});
```

Comment: I've removed the .then((res...) because getInfo it's a void, It's returning `undefined`

Comment: Plus it's returning null because it does not return the value in .then condition from getInfo()

Comment: You've set the value stored at userInfo attribute inside .then() function.

Comment: ok I did a console.log(userInfo) and it shows the object, but I was looking for to get it from my service and from the splash get the info

Comment: @Stuart2041 If you need a synchronous way, I believe that you can't use this storage service

Comment: Well if I can do it on my splash I don't care, but I'm not getting the value

Comment: I got something like this : `{"id":"1","info":"hello"}` but not as object so I can not do userInfo["info"];

Comment: So, just store the object, not the 'stringfy'.

Comment: @Stuart2041 if you did not get it as object then you probably got it as a string. just parse it before you return userInfo["info"]

Comment: @Stuart2041 btw, you are returning an object instead of string. Or you are returing a stringified object. Either way, you are not returning a string. return val["info"] doesn't set val to val["info"]'s value.