# Local Storage data returning Undefined or Null at First time trying to use them

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, local-storage, ionic4

i'm new using Ionic and i'm trying to use local storage, my problem is the following...

I have a login form, that when the login process its successful it stores some data of the server response to the local storage, and then it goes to the next the Main page.
When the main page starts the ngOnInit, i'm trying to retrieve the data from the local storage and display it on a variable call cliente on my html file.
But at the first time i try to do it, in the html file the space where the variable cliente its supposed to be its blank, and using the console log to see the value says Undefined.

If i check the data in the local storage after the successful login all of the info i need is stored and its there.

If i refresh the page it shows everything how its supposed to be.

*I think it has something to do with the values on the localstorage not being ready when i'm trying to display it on the page and when i refresh the page all is ready now*

I've tried several things but none of them works.
This is my code if any of you can help me with ideas.
NOTE: Please **excuse me** if you see some weird things in my code, at the moment i know it looks like Frankenstein but i've changed this code so much that i don't know how to make it work...

**Main.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './../../services/data.service';
import { CanActivate, Router,  ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot,  ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './../../services/auth-service.service';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { GetService } from '../../get.service';

import { BarcodeScanner, BarcodeScannerOptions } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.page.scss'],
})
export class MainPage implements OnInit {
  cliente: any;
  points: any;
  id: any;
  data: any;
  error: any;
  parsedJson: any;
  urlSearchParams: any;
  scannedData: {};

  constructor(private menu: MenuController, private router: Router, private dataService: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
              public authService: AuthService, private storage: Storage, private newsService: GetService,
              private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) {
    this.storage.get('ID').then((val) => {
      this.id = val;
      const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      urlSearchParams.append('cliente', this.id);
      this.newsService
      .getData(`puntos?${urlSearchParams.toString()}`).subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        if (this.data['Error'] === 200) {
          this.storage.set('Puntos', this.data['SaldoPuntos']);
        }
        // console.log(data);
      });
    });
    this.storage.get('Auth').then((val) => {
       console.log(val);
      if (val === 0 || val === null) {
        console.log('Logged Out');
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return;
      }
      if (val !== 0) {
        this.data = this.dataService.getjsonresult();
        this.storage.get('Nombre').then((val) => {
          this.cliente = val;
          // console.log('Your Name is', val);
        });
        this.storage.get('Puntos').then((val) => {
          this.points = parseInt(val);
          // console.log('Your Name is', val);
        });
        // console.log(this.data);
      }
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
      this.storage.get('Nombre').then((val) => {
        this.cliente = val;
        // console.log('Your Name is', val);
      });
    });
    this.storage.get('Puntos').then((val) => {
      this.points = parseInt(val);
      // console.log('Your Name is', val);
    });
  }

  scanCode() {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
      alert('Barcode data ' + JSON.stringify(barcodeData));
      this.scannedData = barcodeData;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error', err);
    });
  }


}
```

**Main Html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="dark">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button contentId="content" autoHide="false"></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button >
        <ion-icon slot="end" name="person" ></ion-icon>        
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: white">MiCliente</h1><img src="../../../assets/icon.png"/> 
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="topright" style="position: fixed; padding-top: 50px;"><ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon><br>Registra tu compra</div> -->
    <div class="welcomeTextDiv">
        <h1 class="welcomeText">BIENVENIDO</h1><br><br>
      </div>
      <h5 style="font-size: 25px; margin: auto; color: red !important; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center" class="errorMessage">
        {{ error }}
      </h5>
      <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: fit-content;" *ngIf="!cliente">
        <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
      </div>
      <div >
      <div class="userDiv">
        <h2 class="userText">{{ cliente }}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="messageDiv">
        <h2 class="messageText">Felicidades has ganado {{ points }} puntos</h2>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div style="text-align: center;color: white">
      <h3>REGISTRA TU COMPRA</h3>
      <ion-button size="large" (click)="scanCode()" color="light">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="barcode"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>  
      </div>
</ion-content>
```

**Login.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { forkJoin, of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
import { CanActivate, Router,   ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { GetService } from '../../get.service';
import { ToastController, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { DataService } from './../../services/data.service';

import { AuthService } from './../../services/auth-service.service';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})

export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  public usuario:any;
    public password:any;
    result: any =[];
    data: any;
    allData: Observable<any>;
  loginJson: any;
  tutorialComplete: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private GetService: GetService, public toastController: ToastController, public menuCtrl: MenuController, 
  private dataService: DataService, private storage: Storage, public authService: AuthService ) {

    // set a key/value
    this.storage.get('Auth').then((val) => {
      console.log(val);
      if (val === '0' || val === ' ' ){
        this.storage.set('ID', 0 );
        this.storage.set('Nombre', '');
        this.storage.set('Puntos', '0' );
        this.storage.set('Auth', '0' );
      } if ( val === '1'){
        console.log('Logged in');
         this.router.navigateByUrl('/menu/main');
        return;
      }
    });

   }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    //this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
   }

   Login(){ 
    var hash = require('hash.js');
    var pass = hash.sha256().update(this.password).digest('hex');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('idusuario', this.usuario);
    urlSearchParams.append('password', pass);
    this.GetService.getData(`LOGINPREM?${urlSearchParams.toString()}`)
      .subscribe(async data => {
        this.result = JSON.stringify(data);   // get data in result variable
        this.allData = JSON.parse(this.result); // parse json data and pass json string
        this.dataService.setjsonresult(this.result);
        // alert(this.dataService.getjsonresult());
        this.storage.set('ID', this.allData['Cliente']);
        this.storage.set('Nombre', this.allData['Nombre']);
        this.storage.set('Puntos', this.allData['SaldoPuntos']);
        this.storage.set('Auth', 1 );
        this.authService.login();
        if (this.allData['Error']== 200) {
          const toast = await this.toastController.create({
            message: "Bienvenido " + this.allData['Nombre'],
            position: 'top',
            duration: 2000
          });
          toast.present();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/menu');
          return false;
        } else {
          const toast = await this.toastController.create({
            message: "Codigo de Error: " + this.allData['Error'] + " Descripcion: " + this.allData['Descripcion'] ,
            position: 'top',
            duration: 2000
          });
          toast.present();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
          return false;
        }   
      });
  }

  async finish() {
    await this.storage.set('tutorialComplete', true);
    await this.storage.set('ID', 0 );
    await this.storage.set('Nombre', '');
    await this.storage.set('Puntos', '0' );
    await this.storage.set('Auth', '0' );
    this.tutorialComplete = this.storage.get('tutorialComplete');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


}
```

I even tried to use a service in the middle to make sure the data was there and ready with the getname:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  data: any;
  jsonresult: any;
  userID: any;
  Points: any;

  constructor( private storage: Storage, ) {
   }
  // Json de Resultado de todos los procesos
  public setjsonresult(jsonresult: any) {
    this.jsonresult = jsonresult;

  }

  public getjsonresult() {
    return this.jsonresult;
  }

 public getPoints() {
    this.storage.get('Puntos').then((val) => {
      this.Points = parseInt(val);
    });
    return this.Points;
  }

  getName() {
    this.storage.get('Nombre').then((val) => {
      return val;
    });
  }
}
```

[image: First display after login]
[image: Second display after refresh the page or going to a different page and coming back]

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44805191/10127727

Comment: please provide minimal code for your issue. 
Also creating stackblitz for your minimal code issue is recommanded